# SQL ORACLE UNPIVOT

Tags: sql, oracle, unpivot

I can not deal with this unpivot.

```
select *
    from (select c.country_id, r.region_id, count(*) liczba
    from countries c join regions r on r.region_id = c.region_id
    group by c.country_id, r.region_id)
    UnPivot(
         count(liczba) for r.region_id in (any))
         order by c.country_id
```

this is code, and still will not work :(

```
select r.region_name, count(*)
from countries c join regions r on r.region_id = c.region_id
group by r.region_name
```

this one works properly.
[image]

"invalid identifier"

[image]

Seconde imagine!

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results so it is clear what you want to accompish.

Comment: You also haven't told us what isn't working - please include the error you get in your question. The `any` keyword only applies for an XML pivot, so you might be trying to do something you can't do with normal static SQL, but it's unclear at the moment. (Also won't `count(*)` in your inner query always be 1?)

Comment: okay, if u may look at post one more time

Comment: when I used normal data, not any it wouldnt worked

Comment: Please don't post images of code or data; not sure what those are showing anyway as they are not the tables your queries refer to. Your unpivot query as posted seems to get ORA-00905 missing keyword, not ORA-00904 invalid identifier. Please include sample data, your actual queries, and the output you are trying to achieve.

Comment: unfortunately, there's no such dynamic way in Oracle in order to unpivot the returning data from a query as you imagine.

Answer (score 2):

Your query does not make sense as:

- `UNPIVOT` is used to transpose columns into rows; you only have 3 columns `country_id`, `region_id` and `liczba`.
- The `UNPIVOT` syntax is:

  ```sql
  UNPIVOT ( value FOR key IN ( column1 AS 'alias1', column2 AS 'alias2' ) )
  ```

  You cannot have a aggregation expression as the value.
- You need to specify which columns you are `UNPIVOT`ing to rows; you cannot use `any` unless you have defined a column called `any`.

You appear to want to use `PIVOT` rather than `UNPIVOT`.

---

> I would like to see, how many people work in each job_id

Use `GROUP BY` and `COUNT`:

```sql
SELECT job_id,
       COUNT(DISTINCT EMPLOYEE_ID) AS number_of_employees
FROM   employees
GROUP BY job_id
```

> using unpivot

That's not what `UNPIVOT` is for; `UNPIVOT` converts columns to rows whereas you want to aggregate rows together.

Comment: okay, got it. So, if I would like to see, how many people work in each job_id, what should I do? (picture in a post)