# oracle SQL - unpivot

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, unpivot

Can u tell me, why it wont work?:)

```
    select *
from( select r.region_id, c.country_id
from countries c join regions r on r.region_id = c.region_id)
unpivot(
    valuee for columnValue in (r.region_id))
```

ORA-01748: only simple column names allowed here
01748. 00000 -  "only simple column names allowed here"

Comment: [You still haven't explained](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60952290/266304) why you think you want to unpivot, or what you think it will achieve.

Answer (score 1):

With this part:

```
select *
```

You are selecting columns: `region_id` and `country_id` from your inner select. So you do not need `r.region_id` in your UNPIVOT section, only `region_id`.
This code is correct(without error):

```
select *
from(select r.region_id
            , c.country_id
     from countries c 
     join regions r on r.region_id = c.region_id)
unpivot(valuee for columnValue in (region_id));
```

Comment: Hi @MateuszOsiński you still have not marked this answer as correct ?

Answer (score 0):

Your query is strange and it isn't really clear what you're trying to achieve; but following up on @VBoka's correction of your code, you don't actually need the join at all (unless you have countries with non-existent regions) - you can do:

```
select *
from (
  select region_id, country_id
 from countries
)
unpivot(valuee for columnValue in (region_id));
```

But you can get the same result without unpivoting; with the join if you have a real reason to include it:

```
select c.country_id, 'REGION_ID' as columnvalue, r.region_id as valuee
from countries c
join regions r on r.region_id = c.region_id;
```

or without the join:

```
select country_id, 'REGION_ID' as columnvalue, region_id as valuee
from countries;
```

Either way you get a result set with one row for every country.